# Changing Maps styles without resetting previous settings

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add some [custom options](https://i.gyazo.com/c2ed25ae637cd3e04e5d30207f8ea951.png) to my map so that the user can toggle certain things on and off like Transit, roads, and POI's.  However it seems that when I use `setOptions`, it forgets my previous settings and applies the new ones.

For example.  In the code below, transit icon labels are turned off by default.  However when I click the POI toggle, the transit icons would appear.

How do I overcome this obstacle?  I tried a few ways like:

- Creating a variable that stores the styles.  However I don't see how I can retrieve just the settings I want to change
- Creating a layer with the styles.  I tried doing this but there doesn't seem to be a way to create layer with default Google Maps styles.

---

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 43.693226, lng: -79.383184},
    styles: [
        {
            featureType: 'transit',
            elementType: 'labels.icon',
            stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
        {
            featureType: 'poi',
            elementType: 'labels',
            stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
        },
    ]
});

var poiToggleOn = false;
document.getElementById('poiToggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (poiToggleOn === false) {
        poiToggleOn = true;
        map.setOptions({styles: [
            {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'labels',
                stylers: [{visibility: 'on'}]
            }
        ]})
    } else {
        poiToggleOn = false;
        map.setOptions({styles: [
            {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'labels',
                stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
            }
        ]})
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems rather straightforward: **you have to keep track of the styles that you have already added**, and whenever you call `map.setOptions({styles:...})` pass all the previously added styles to the map. The method of how you choose to *keep track* of previously added styles is up to you.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately what is straightforward to you is not as straightforward to a newbie like me.  I did manage to get it working with a bunch of if statements.  Not the best solution but it works

Comment: There is are samples in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/style-selector and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/hiding-features